# Uploading video to Google Drive programmatically (Android API)

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I have followed the Drive API guide (https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/drive.html) and my app now uploads photos smoothly, but I am now trying to upload videos (mp4) without success.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? The video is a newly generated mp4 file and I have the path to where it is stored on the device.

For pictures its done like this:

```
Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mDriveClient).setResultCallback(
    new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {

@Override
public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
        return;
    }
    OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
    // Write the bitmap data from it.
    ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bitmapStream);
    try {
        outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
    }
    image.recycle();
    outputStream = null;
    String title = Shared.getOutputMediaFile(Shared.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE).getName();
    MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
        .setMimeType("image/jpeg").setTitle(title)
        .build();
    Log.i(TAG, "Creating new pic on Drive (" + title + ")");

    Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mDriveClient,
        mPicFolderDriveId).createFile(mDriveClient,
        metadataChangeSet, result.getDriveContents());
        }
    });
}
```

What I am interested in is an alternative for a File, in this case pointing to a "video/mp4".

Comment: how to upload csv file to gdrive like what you did for image/video

Comment: If you are uploading large video like 2 GB this code will crash...You write in the ByteArrayOutputStream the whole file...not good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without getting into much detail, just a few pointers:

Anything you want to upload (image, text, video,...) consists from

1. creating a file
2. setting metadata (title, MIME type, description,...)
3. setting content (byte stream)

The demo you mention does it with an image (JPEG bytestream) and you need to do it with video. So, the changes you need to implement are:

- replace the  "image/jpeg" MIME type with the one you need for your
  video
- copy your video stream (*outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray())...*)

to the content.

These are the only changes you need to make. Google Drive Android API doesn't care what is your content and metadata, it just grabs it a shoves it up to Google Drive.

In Google Drive, apps (web, android,...) read the metadata and content, and treat it accordingly.

Comment: i am trying to upload csv file once the user login with his account,but i am unable to use services to upload is this any way is there to upload here my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738070/upload-csv-file-to-gdrive-progrmmatically-shows-issue-in-service

Comment: I have actually read your question on SO, but unfortunately I am too busy at the moment. You may try to download this test, I smacked together a LONG time ago - so it may be outdated. https://github.com/seanpjanson/140201-GDAA. It writes dummy text and creates files on the Drive. Since CSV files are text files, you may be successful using it (but modify the MIME type). I will post a new version of this within 2 weeks I hope.

Answer (score 2):

So this my complete code how I achieved uploading a video.
Steps:

- Fetch video file from uri(as in my case).
- Get the byte array from bytearray outputstream as mentioned in the code
- write the byte array to the ouputStream
- the api will upload the file in the background

public class UploadVideo extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DriveClient mDriveClient;
DriveResourceClient mDriveResourceClient;
GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount;
String TAG = "Drive";
private final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2013;
Task<DriveContents> createContentsTask;
String uri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_video);
    //Fetching uri or path from previous activity.
    uri = getIntent().getStringExtra("uriVideo");
    //Get previously signed in account.
    googleSignInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
        mDriveClient = Drive.getDriveClient(getApplicationContext(), googleSignInAccount);
        mDriveResourceClient =
                Drive.getDriveResourceClient(getApplicationContext(), googleSignInAccount);
    }
    else Toast.makeText(this, "Login again and retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    createContentsTask = mDriveResourceClient.createContents();
    findViewById(R.id.uploadVideo).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                createFile();
        }
    });
}

private void createFile() {
    // [START create_file]
    final Task<DriveFolder> rootFolderTask = mDriveResourceClient.getRootFolder();
    final Task<DriveContents> createContentsTask = mDriveResourceClient.createContents();
    Tasks.whenAll(rootFolderTask, createContentsTask)
            .continueWithTask(new Continuation<Void, Task<DriveFile>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<DriveFile> then(@NonNull Task<Void> task) throws Exception {
                    DriveFolder parent = rootFolderTask.getResult();
                    DriveContents contents = createContentsTask.getResult();
                    File file = new File(uri);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                        baos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
                    }
                    OutputStream outputStream = contents.getOutputStream();
                    outputStream.write(baos.toByteArray());

                    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setTitle("MyVideo.mp4") // Provide you video name here
                            .setMimeType("video/mp4") // Provide you video type here
                            .build();

                    return mDriveResourceClient.createFile(parent, changeSet, contents);
                }
            })
            .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                    new OnSuccessListener<DriveFile>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DriveFile driveFile) {
                            Toast.makeText(Upload.this, "Upload Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create file", e);
                    finish();
                }
            });
    // [END create_file]
}
```

}

Comment: Please explain your answer rather than providing mere links. Links might change over time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload any file to Google Drive, then use the below code with Synchronization task, it will upload your file to Drive.

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() 
                {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) 
            {
               String file_type="video/mp4"; //write your file type
               File body = new File();                   
               File FileRtr = null;
               body.setTitle(myfile.getName());
               body.setMimeType(file_type);
               body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(LocationID))); //LocationID means the path in the drive e where you want to upload it
            try 
            {
              FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(file_type, myfile);
              FileRtr = mService.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

              if ( FileRtr != null) 
              {
                System.out.println("File uploaded: " +  FileRtr.getTitle());

              }
              }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                 System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                return null;

            } 
            protected void onPostExecute(String token) 
            {
             Toast.makeText(mContext, "Uploaded Successfuly",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
            };
        task.execute();
```

Comment: Pir, you are suggesting RESTful API (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/), whereas the question is in the domain of GDAA (https://developers.google.com/drive/android/). It is not a good idea to mix these 2 because of timing / latency issues in GDAA. As I mentioned a few times already, I managed to 'GDAA' write to a file deleted by RESTful hours after deletion. Or create a file in a folder long gone.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Thanks to seanpj, turns out I was overestimating the difficulty of this, I now use this method to upload both images and videos:

```
/**
 * Create a new file and save it to Drive.
 */
private void saveFiletoDrive(final File file, final String mime) {
    // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mDriveClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
                    // If the operation was not successful, we cannot do
                    // anything
                    // and must
                    // fail.
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
                        return;
                    }
                     Log.i(TAG, "Connection successful, creating new contents...");
                    // Otherwise, we can write our data to the new contents.
                    // Get an output stream for the contents.
                    OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents()
                            .getOutputStream();
                    FileInputStream fis;
                    try {
                        fis = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int n;
                        while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
                            baos.write(buf, 0, n);
                        byte[] photoBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                        outputStream.write(photoBytes);

                        outputStream.close();
                        outputStream = null;
                        fis.close();
                        fis = null;

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to write file contents." + e1.getMessage());
                    }

                    String title = file.getName();
                    MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setMimeType(mime).setTitle(title).build();

                    if (mime.equals(MIME_PHOTO)) {
                        if (VERBOSE)
                            Log.i(TAG, "Creating new photo on Drive (" + title
                                    + ")");
                        Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mDriveClient,
                                mPicFolderDriveId).createFile(mDriveClient,
                                metadataChangeSet,
                                result.getDriveContents());
                    } else if (mime.equals(MIME_VIDEO)) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Creating new video on Drive (" + title
                                + ")");
                        Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mDriveClient,
                                mVidFolderDriveId).createFile(mDriveClient,
                                metadataChangeSet,
                                result.getDriveContents());
                    }

                    if (file.delete()) {
                        if (VERBOSE)
                            Log.d(TAG, "Deleted " + file.getName() + " from sdcard");
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to delete " + file.getName() + " from sdcard");
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to upload file to Google Drive without using Drive API. Using Intent you can implement this. (Tested on Android 12)

```
String your_file_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath()
+ "/XYZ/Database/"+FILE_NAME+"_");

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "authorities_from_manifest_file_of_provider_tag",new File(your_file_path));
        intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs"); //Google Drive 
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,photoURI);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Save Backup"));
```

You must have added working File Provider in your Manifest before implementing of this.

Note: "authorities_from_manifest_file_of_provider_tag" is the attribute value of `android:authorities` this from manifest. i.e -

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.your.packageName.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```