# Upload file to Googledrive programmatically using Android API

Tags: android, csv, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Once I logged in gdrive I tried to upload csv file programmatically. But it throws error in service.

```
public class Gdriveactivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = "android-drive-quickstart";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 3;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Bitmap mBitmapToSave;

    private void saveFiletoDrive() {

        ResultCallback<DriveApi.ContentsResult> contentsCallback = new
                ResultCallback<DriveApi.ContentsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.ContentsResult result) {

                    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle("New file")
                    .setMimeType("text/plain").build();


                    Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                    .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, null /* DriveContents */)
                    .setResultCallback(this);
                }
            };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
            // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
            // failures.
            // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        }
        // Connect the client. Once connected, the camera is launched.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE:
                // Called after a photo has been taken.
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Store the image data as a bitmap for writing later.
                    mBitmapToSave = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR:
                // Called after a file is saved to Drive.
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Image successfully saved.");
                    mBitmapToSave = null;
                    // Just start the camera again for another photo.
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE),
                            REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);

                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
        Toast.makeText(Gdriveactivity.this, "connected failed", 1000).show();
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            // show the localized error dialog.
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
            return;
        }

        // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, 
        // authorization
        // dialog is displayed to the user.
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");
        if (mBitmapToSave == null) {
            // This activity has no UI of its own. Just start the camera.
            Toast.makeText(Gdriveactivity.this, "connected", 1000).show();
            //startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE),
            //   REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            //   return;
        }
        insertFile();
    }
```

Once I connected to gdrive account only I tried to upload file. But it shows error in service.
I can't use Drive service to initialize also because I imported drive in gms way

```
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ParentReference;
```

Comment: @ianhanniballake i am unable to use services it shows error here File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute(); service cannot be resolved.

Comment: So what's the error message?

Comment: import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive; i cant use this import function.I can declare like this Drive service but how to initialize Drive here.if i did like this it showing error like this The method files() is undefined for the type Drive

Comment: @ianhanniballake is this my way of approaching to insert file is wrong??

Comment: where is "service" defined?

Comment: @pinoyyid i am confusing that how to define service?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of methods of [Creating a Google Drive File](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file) including using a [CreateFileActivityBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/CreateFileActivityBuilder.html) to allow the user to pick exactly where on their Google Drive they would like to create the file or programmatically calling [createFile()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveFolder.html#createFile(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet,%20com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents)) on a [DriveFolder](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveFolder.html) you have. Ways of retrieving the appropriate `DriveFolder` include:

- [Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html#getRootFolder(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) (for the public root directory)
- [Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html#getAppFolder(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) (for your application private directory - the user cannot see these files, only how much storage space they take)
- through a result of [Drive.DriveApi.query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html#query(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Query)).

Comment: is this i need to write any extra class to store authentication something,bcz once logged-in i need to upload file/csv programmatically not manually

Comment: Once you've logged in once, you can log in again without any user intervention (i.e., from a background service) assuming the user doesn't manually remove access to your app. You probably do want to save the created `DriveFile`'s drive ID via `getDriveId().encodeToString()` - that will allow you to update the file very easily.

Comment: have you see my above code..first time only i logged in,next time its not asking user intrevention.is this line of code is correct way of inserting file File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

Comment: Your logging in code looks fine, but you need to use the `createFile()` method as per my answer to create the file.

Comment: in this code ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult> contentsCallback = new
            ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
     
        public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
is that DriveContentResult is giving error

Comment: You'll need to be more specific with what error you are getting - the easiest way is to edit your original section and add the new code you have and the exact error message you are receiving.

Comment: ,look out this link here i mentioned that issue with code http://pastebin.com/XzrQ157F

Comment: The error message says your ResultCallback needs to be a `ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>`, not `ResultCallback<(DriveContentsResult>`

Comment: ,no success if i use that one too

Comment: .setResultCallback(this); if i remove the line like this,with the code changes nothing happens http://pastebin.com/0UTiQhVN

Comment: issue is that setResultCallback(this) only.i look those sample code also

Comment: ,create file and folder is now fine,but how to upload/insert file to the folder .it doesnt have insert keyword

Comment: Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder() returns null