# Upload video to google drive using android api

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I need my project to do the same thing as the code in [Quick Start Google Drive API](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) using the Google Drive API. Instead of an image, I need upload a recorded video with my app. I don't know how to create files, parse the result, or create a byte ArrayList. I tried [this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27409953/solved-uploading-video-to-google-drive-programmatically-android-api?rq=1) but it isn't working.

```
  /**
 * Copyright 2013 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 * in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
 * License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either
 * express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

/**
 * Android Drive Quickstart activity. This activity takes a photo and saves it
 * in Google Drive. The user is prompted with a pre-made dialog which allows
 * them to choose the file location.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "drive-quickstart";
    private static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 3;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Bitmap mBitmapToSave;
    private File file;

    /**
     * Create a new file and save it to Drive.
     */
    private void saveFileToDrive() {
        // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");
        final Bitmap image = mBitmapToSave;
        final File file1 = file;
        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
                        // If the operation was not successful, we cannot do anything
                        // and must
                        // fail.
                        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
                            return;
                        }
                        // Otherwise, we can write our data to the new contents.
                        Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");
                        // Get an output stream for the contents.
                        OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
                        // Write the bitmap data from it.

                        outputStream = result.getDriveContents()
                                .getOutputStream();
                        FileInputStream fis;
                        try {
                            fis = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
                            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                            int n;
                            while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
                                baos.write(buf, 0, n);
                            byte[] photoBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                            outputStream.write(photoBytes);

                            outputStream.close();
                            outputStream = null;
                            fis.close();
                            fis = null;

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to write file contents." + e1.getMessage());
                        }

                        /*image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);*/


                        // Create the initial metadata - MIME type and title.
                        // Note that the user will be able to change the title later.
                        MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setMimeType("video/mp4").setTitle("Android Photo.mp4").build();
                        // Create an intent for the file chooser, and start it.
                        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                                .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                                .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                                .setInitialDriveContents(result.getDriveContents())
                                .build(mGoogleApiClient);
                        try {
                            startIntentSenderForResult(
                                    intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
                        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
            // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
            // failures.
            // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        // Connect the client. Once connected, the camera is launched.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE:
                // Called after a photo has been taken.
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Store the image data as a bitmap for writing later.
                    Context context = null;
                    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), String.valueOf(REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR));
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR:
                // Called after a file is saved to Drive.
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Image successfully saved.");
                    file = null;
                    // Just start the camera again for another photo.
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE),
                            CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            // show the localized error dialog.
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
            return;
        }
        // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
        // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
        // authorization
        // dialog is displayed to the user.
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");
        if (file == null) {
            // This activity has no UI of its own. Just start the camera.
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE),
                    CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        saveFileToDrive();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
    }
}
```